# Bold attribute doesn't work

Tags: emacs, fonts, elisp

I'm trying to make font in Emacs a little bolder. I use Inconsolata and here is a snippet from my `.emacs`:

```
(when window-system
  (set-face-attribute 'default
                      nil
                      :font "Inconsolata"
                      :height 120
                      :weight 'bold) ; <- this line does not affect rendering
  (require 'color-theme-solarized)
  (color-theme-solarized-dark)
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
                 '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN" 0)))
```

I know that Inconsolata can be rendered bold, but for some reason Emacs always renders it with normal weight. Maybe I should enable something before trying to change font?

Comment: It sounds like you found your answer. I'll just mention that it is also often the case that a given font has no `bold` variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, original Inconsolata does not have bold variant, applications emulate Inconsolata Bold by increasing character width. This is why one can use 'bold' variant of Inconsolata in some of them.

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconsolata):

> when Inconsolata was added to Google Fonts, it was fully hinted and a bold variant was added

So it is important which version of the font one uses. I've removed original Inconsolata and installed Google Fonts this way (Arch Linux):

```
# yaourt -S ttf-google-fonts-git
```

If you encounter such a problem, try searching for a similar package for your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
(when window-system
  (set-face-attribute 'default
                      nil
                      :font "Inconsolata"
                      :height 120
                      :bold t)
  (require 'color-theme-solarized)
  (color-theme-solarized-dark)
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
                 '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN" 0)))
```

Comment: 'Symbol's value as variable is void: bold' - this is what I get.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll give it another try and see where I went wrong -- sorry.

Comment: How about?: `:bold t`  On an OSX box, that gives me `-*-Monaco-bold-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`

Comment: No effect. [This page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) says that one should use `:weight`, there is no such attribute as `:bold`.

Comment: `:bold` is an *alias* for `:weight`

Comment: I tried other fonts (Sans), and `:weight 'bold` works for them. Strange.

Comment: If that is the case, then your code is fine the way it was.  It's another issue probably.

Comment: How about using `:family` instead of `:font` -- `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Inconsolata" :height 120 :weight 'bold)` -- that gives me `-*-Helvetica-bold-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`

Comment: If you found the answer, please post it and accept it. If @lawlist's answer was the answer then please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I ended up here trying to find update of what I'm
doing now (haven't found yet)... but this simple trick may be
useful (year 2019 linux X, emacs 26.1 Gtk+3, and xft fonts):

```
emacs -xrm Xft.embolden:true -fn Inconsolata-14
```

This makes all variabts (regular, italics, bold, bolditalics)
(even) bolder when such variants exist. `-fn Inconsolate-15:weight=bold` affected only regular for me (without that -xrm ... option).